# Suppose that gcd($a,p$) = gcd($b,p$) = 1, and neither of the congruences $x^2 ...

Tags: number-theory, congruences, legendre-symbol

Suppose that gcd($a,p$) = gcd($b,p$) = 1, and neither of the congruences $x^2 \equiv a$ mod $p$ or $x^2 \equiv b$ mod $p$ has a solution. Show that $x^2 \equiv ab$ mod $p$ does have a solution.

- Having a tough time with this problem, went to my professor for some advice and he hinted at utilizing quadratic reciprocity and Lengendre symbol. I understand the formula for quadratic reciprocity but don't understand how this ties in with Legendre and helps solve this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Quadratic reciprocity is irrelevant. One can use the formula $(ab/p)=(a/p)(b/p)$. This is kind of cheating, one should really prove that the formula holds.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid quadratic reciprocity and use [Euler's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion):
$$
a^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1,
\quad
b^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv -1
\implies
(ab)^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv (-1)(-1)=1 \bmod p
$$
and so $ab$ is a quadratic residue.